# Printing out path from views - /drupal/ appears twice

Tags: 7, views, uri

I'm using this to print out a custom link format in views. I'm using it in the unformatted views tpl.php file.

```
<?php print l('<span class="link-spanner"> a</span>',
              $view->style_plugin->row_tokens[$id]['[path]'],
              array ('html' => TRUE)); ?>
```

This line calls the relevant HTML path:

```
$view->style_plugin->row_tokens[$id]['[path]']
```

For example it might contain the value: localhost/drupal/node/31.

But when I put it in the l() function I get localhost/drupal//drupal/node/31.

Anyone know how I can stop the double print out? This is driving me mad.

Comment: I see two problems there, first one is with the path format. The path should start and ends without slash, for example: `node/1`. In your case, `$view->style_plugin->row_tokens[$id]['[path]']` returns `/localhost/drupal/somepath` That's why you've got the additional slash. The second problem is with the path string, because it should be an internal path or external URL, such as "node/34" or [http://example.com/foo](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7)

Comment: Cheers that cleared up the confusion. I found another thread in the end and realised that I could just build the relative path using the Node ID. Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php print l('<span class="link-spanner"></span>',
'node/' . $view->result[$id]->_field_data['nid']['entity']->vid, 
array ('html' => TRUE)); ?>
```

Here is the final solution.

It will add the NID on the end of node/ and create the internal path "node/x". If you're using Pathauto this will still work.